# Change display of teaser based on content type of page in which it is displayed

Tags: 7, nodes

So I know you can define how to display a teaser for different content types using `if($teaser)` in node--content_type.tpl but how can I add logic to render the teaser in different formats depending on the content type of the page in which it is being displayed?

I want to do this

```
if($teaser && CONTENT_TYPE_OF_PAGE_THAT_TEASER_IS_DISPLAYED_ON == content_type)
```

within node--content_type.tpl is there a way to go about this?

For example I have teasers of content type blog. But I want these teasers to display different when they are on a page of content-type:blog, to when they are displayed on a page of content-type:level_3.

Thanks for your time

Comment: no, it's not the pleace, you should do it with a preprocess function in a module or the theme template.php file.

Comment: OK, so could you give me an example of a function to create this behavior please?

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. In *node--content_type.tpl* I can get the content type of the page in which the teaser is displayed like so:

```
$node = menu_get_object($type='node');
```

I can then use logic to render my teasers in different ways depending on the page's content type:

```
if($teaser && ($node->type == 'my_content_type')){
    //render in this way
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tray [display suit](http://drupal.org/project/ds)?

Display suit let you configure how you want to print the teaser and the full content type with a great UI

Oskar